# Validation loss being lower than training loss, and loss reduction in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm training a unet model on the TACO dataset, and I'm having problems with my output. My validation loss is quite a bit lower than my training loss, and I'm not entirely sure if this is a good thing. 
Since the TACO dataset is a COCO format dataset with 1500 images, I split my data by having my train_generator contain images 0-1199, and my val_generator with images 1200-1499. I then augment my data using the following function:

```
def augmentationsGenerator(gen, augGeneratorArgs, seed=None):
    # Initialize the image data generator with args provided
    image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(**augGeneratorArgs)

    # Remove the brightness argument for the mask. Spatial arguments similar to image.
    augGeneratorArgs_mask = augGeneratorArgs.copy()
    _ = augGeneratorArgs_mask.pop('brightness_range', None)
    # Initialize the mask data generator with modified args
    mask_gen = ImageDataGenerator(**augGeneratorArgs_mask)

    np.random.seed(seed if seed is not None else np.random.choice(range(9999)))

    for img, mask in gen:
        seed = np.random.choice(range(9999))
        # keep the seeds syncronized otherwise the augmentation of the images 
        # will end up different from the augmentation of the masks
        g_x = image_gen.flow(255*img, 
                             batch_size = img.shape[0], 
                             seed = seed, 
                             shuffle=True)
        g_y = mask_gen.flow(mask, 
                             batch_size = mask.shape[0], 
                             seed = seed, 
                             shuffle=True)

        img_aug = next(g_x)/255.0

        mask_aug = next(g_y)


        yield img_aug, mask_aug
```

with the following arguments:

```
augGeneratorArgs = dict(featurewise_center = False, 
                        samplewise_center = False,
                        rotation_range = 5, 
                        width_shift_range = 0.01, 
                        height_shift_range = 0.01, 
                        brightness_range = (0.8,1.2),
                        shear_range = 0.01,
                        zoom_range = [1, 1.25],  
                        horizontal_flip = True, 
                        vertical_flip = False,
                        fill_mode = 'reflect',
                        data_format = 'channels_last')
```

My model code is:

```
IMG_WIDTH = 224
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_CHANNELS = 3
epochs = 25
validation_steps = val_size
steps_per_epoch = train_size
x = 32

##Creating the model

initializer = "he_normal"

###Building U-Net Model

##Input Layer
inputs = Input((IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_CHANNELS))

##Converting inputs to float
s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)

##Contraction
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(s)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c1)
p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*2, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(p1)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*2, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c2)
p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c2)

c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*4, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(p2)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*4, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c3)
p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c3)

c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*8, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(p3)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*8, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c4)
p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c4)

c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(p4)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c5)

##Expansion
u6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(x*8, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c5)
u6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*8, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(u6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*8, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c6)

u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(x*4, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c6)
u7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*4, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(u7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*4, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c7)

u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(x*2, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c7)
u8 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*2, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(u8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x*2, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c8)

u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(x, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c8)
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(u9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(x, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c9)

##Output Layer
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(61, (1,1), activation="softmax")(c9)

##Defining Model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])

##Compiling Model
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])


##Defining callbacks
callbacks = [
             tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('/content/drive/My Drive/THESIS/taco_2-2_final_retry.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True),
             tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=6, monitor="val_loss"),
             tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logs),
             tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience = 2, min_lr = 0.001)]

##Training the model
results = model.fit(x = train_gen_aug, 
                    validation_data = val_gen_aug, 
                    steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch, 
                    validation_steps = validation_steps, 
                    epochs = epochs, 
                    callbacks=callbacks,
                    verbose = True)
```

First few epochs yield the following results:

```
Epoch 1/25
1200/1200 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.8035 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9495
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.22116, saving model to /content/drive/My Drive/THESIS/taco_2-2_final_retry.h5
1200/1200 [==============================] - 7408s 6s/step - loss: 0.8035 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9495 - val_loss: 0.2212 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9859 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 2/25
1200/1200 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.7942 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9501
Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 0.22116 to 0.21732, saving model to /content/drive/My Drive/THESIS/taco_2-2_final_retry.h5
1200/1200 [==============================] - 6378s 5s/step - loss: 0.7942 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9501 - val_loss: 0.2173 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9861 - lr: 0.0010
```

So my question is, is having a validation loss lower than my training loss okay/acceptable? And how do I further reduce my validation loss? I'm aiming for something around 0.0x. Do I add more dropout layers or increase the dropout values? Reduce/increase number of neurons per layer?

Comment: Validation loss being less than training loss suggests that your model can handle even more parameters (in the form of additional layers, for instance) before being in danger of overfitting (and potentially perform better than it currently is).

Answer (score 2):

Almost always training loss is lower than validation loss, so it's pretty much okay.

Regarding reducing your val loss, you'll have to work around various things.
Such as:

1) Varying your augGeneratorArgs hyper-parameters

2) Adding more layers or neurons per layer

3) Adding more dropouts to reduce overfitting.

4) Increase/Decrease epochs

5) Plot visualization of train/val loss to check if your model is overfitting.

Comment: I'm sorry, I seem to have mistyped. Is it alright if my validation loss is lower than my training loss? And how would you add/increase the dropouts? Each conv block already has a dropout layer, so I'm not sure where I should add more. Would increasing the dropout values help instead?